# Classes with pointers and binary files

Tags: c++, class, pointers, binaryfiles

Well guys/girls, I already asked this but I think I didn't explain good and I couldn't find the solution so I'll ask again with more details and explain more the context of my problem.

I have two classes that contain user data and I want to save them in binary files. On the other hand, I have a template class responsible for save these classes.

There is a really important fact that I have to mention: in the beginning I chose encode a auxiliary class for any class that I would save. This auxiliary class is responsible of writing/reading of data. The original classes have string members and the auxiliary classes have pointers to char. But recently, looking for more simplicity and flexibility,  I chose to combine the original class, that contains the benefits of string class ;and its auxiliary that has the pointers that makes the class more comfortable at the moment of save it. So, instead of have two classes, I have one class that handles the input/output of data and the write/read of data.

This change looks something like this:

```
class AuxNOTE;

//Original Class: Input/Output of Data
class NOTE{
private:
    string _Category;
    string _Description;
public:
    NOTE() : _Category( "" ) , _Description( "" ) { }

    NOTE( const NOTE & note ) : _Category( note._Category ) 
                              , _Description( note._Description ) { }

    NOTE( string category , string description ) : _Category( category)                                                    
                                                 , _Description( description ) { }

    NOTE( const AuxNOTE & aux ) : _Category( aux._Category ) 
                                , _Description( aux._Description ) { }

    NOTE & operator=( const NOTE & note ){ 
         _Category = note._Category;
         _Description = note._Description;
         return *this;
}

    NOTE & operator=( const AuxNOTE & aux ){
         _Category = string( aux._Category );
         _Description = string( aux._Description );
         return *this;
}

    string GetCategory() const { return _Category; }
    string GetDescription() const { return _Description; }
    void SetCategory( string category ) { _Category = category; }
    void SetDescription( string description ) { _Description = description; }
}; 

//Auxliary Class: Writing/Reading of Data to/from binary files
class AuxNOTE{
private:
     char _Category[50];
     char _Description[255];
public:
     AuxNOTE(){ }

     AuxNOTE( const NOTE & note ){
          strcpy( _Category , note._Category );
          strcpy( _Description , note._Description);
     }
     AuxNOTE & operator=( const NOTE & note ){
          strcpy( _Category , note._Category );
          strcpy( _Description , note._Description );
          return *this;
     }
};
```

What I have now is something like this:

```
//Class NOTE: Input/Output of Data and Writing/Reading to/from binary files.
// .h file
class NOTE{
private:
   char * _Category;
   char * _Description;
public:
   NOTE();
   NOTE( const NOTE & note );
   NOTE( string category , string description );
   NOTE & operator=( const NOTE & note )

   string GetCategory() const;
   string GetDescription() const;
   void SetCategory( string category );
   void SetDescription( string description );
};

// .cpp file
#include "NOTE.h"

NOTE :: NOTE() : _Category( nullptr ) ,_Description( nullptr )
{

}

NOTE :: NOTE( string description , string category )
     : _Category ( new char[ category.size() + 1 ] )
     , _Categoria( new char[ description.size() + 1 ] )
{
    strcpy( _Categoria , category.c_str() );
    strcpy( _Descripcion , description.c_str() );
}

NOTE :: NOTE (const NOTE & copy )
     : _Category( nullptr )
     , _Description nullptr )
{
    if( copy._Description != nullptr ){
        _Description =  new char[ strlen( copy._Description ) + 1 ];
        strcpy( _Description , copy._Description );
    }

    if( copy._Category != nullptr ){
        _Category = new char[ strlen( copy._Category ) + 1 ];
        strcpy( _Category , copy._Category );
    }
}

NOTE :: ~NOTE() {
    if( _Description != nullptr ) delete [] _Description;
    if( _Category != nullptr ) delete [] _Category;
}

//Get Methods
string NOTE :: GetDescription() const { return string(_Description); }

string NOTE :: GetCategory() const { return string(_Category); }

//Set Methods
void NOTE :: SetDescription( string description ){

    if( _Description != nullptr ) delete [] _Description;
    _Description = new char[ description.size() + 1 ];
    strcpy( _Description , description.c_str() );
}

void NOTE :: SetCategory( string category ){

    if( m_Category != nullptr ) delete [] _Category;
    _Category = new char[ category.size() + 1 ];
    strcpy( _Category , category.c_str() );
}

//Operators
NOTE & NOTE :: operator=( const NOTE & note ){
    if( note._Description != nullptr ) SetDescription( note.GetDescription() );
    if( note._Category != nullptr ) SetCategory( note.GetCategory() );
    return *this;
}
```

Note that the public interface looks like if the NOTE class works with string members but it doesn't because it works with pointers to char. Thus the NOTE class can be saved without any problem. However, the class is not responsible at all of writing/reading but I created another class that can save any class as long as these classes have members that can be saved.

And the class that is responsible of this is a template class and looks like this:

```
template< class T >
class SAVER{
private:
   vector< T > _Vector;
   string _File;
public:
   SAVER( string file );
   ~SAVER();
};


template< class T >
SAVER< T > :: SAVER( string file ) : _File( file ){

    assert( _File != "" );

    ifstream file( _File , ios::binary );

    if( file.is_open() ){

        T obj;
        while( file.read( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&obj) , sizeof(obj) ) )
            _Vector.push_back( obj );
    }
}


template< class T >
Saver< T > :: ~Saver() {

    if( _Vector.empty() )
           return;

    ofstream file( _File , ios::binary | ios::trunc );  
    assert( file.is_open() );

    auto itr = _Vector.begin();
    auto end = _Vector.end();

    while( itr != end ){
        if ( !file.write( reinterpret_cast<char*>( &itr ) , sizeof(itr) ) ) 
           break;
        itr++;
     }
}
```

The SAVER's constructor handles the reading and puts the data( e.g NOTE objects ) in its vector. The destroyer handles the writing of all vector's objects into the corresponding binary file.

I got to clear that my errors aren't compile error but they are runtime errors.

Now, This is the problem I have:

When I execute the entire program, it has to read the binary file but it breaks. I open it with the debugger and I see that the program finishes in this line with a "segmentation fault error" and this comes from the SAVER constructor:

```
NOTE :: ~NOTE() {
    if( _Description != nullptr ) delete [] _Description; //It breaks at this line
    if( _Category != nullptr ) delete [] _Category;
}
```

In the debugger I can see the value of _Description and next to it appears an memory error that says: error: Cannot access memory at address (value of _Description).

Why is this happen? Do you see any error? If you need more information or you don't understand something just let me know.

Comment: _"Well guys/girls,"_ Girls and dames 1st please if you want to be considered a serious gent.

Answer (score 1):

First, search the internet for "c++ serialization library".  What you are performing is called *serialization*.

Pointers and any class that contains pointers cannot be written verbatim to a file.  The pointers are locations in memory.  There is no guarantee by most Operating Systems that your program will have the exact memory locations next time it is executed.  Your program may run in different areas of memory which change where your data is stored.

There are techniques around this, such as either writing the quantity first, then the data or writing the data then some kind of sentinel (such as the '\0' in C-Style strings).

Consider not writing as a binary file, but using formatted textual representations.  A number will be read in by many platforms and converted to native representations.  A native representation written in binary mode to a file, many not be the same on another platform (look up "Endianess").  Also, most text editors and word processors can easily read text files.  Reading and interpreting a binary file is more difficult.

Unless your application's bottleneck is I/O bound and the I/O timing is critical, consider using textual representation of data.  It is easier to read (especially when debugging your program) and easily portable.

Comment: _"Consider not writing as a binary file, but using formatted textual representations."_ There are more advanced and still wire friendly techniques like google protocol buffers.

Comment: They may be *wire friendly*, but simple text editors still have problems displaying the content of binary files.  After most of the functionality is working correctly, the data format can be altered.  At my shop, we are still outputting text format even though the binary data is 1/2 the size and 1/2 the time.  The correctness and robustness outweighs the data transfer benefits.

Comment: At my shop, we use google protobuf to overcome any problems regarding wire size, endianess aso. Robustness isn't even in question, it just does the job as intended. There are tools provided for the technique to extract human readable contents easily. So no real excuse to stick to text formatting.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I understand what you mean. I'm not writing the value of the c string but I'm writing the memory value of all char pointers at that runtime. However, I still don't understand something: note that in the beginning I used an auxiliary class for any class that I would save, as you can see, I used in it an oversized static vector. Why does this worked? So, use oversized static vectors is a simple and a better idea than fight with dynamic vectors?

Answer (score 1):

> In the debugger I can see the value of _Description and next to it appears an memory error that says: error: Cannot access memory at address (value of _Description).

Sure, you cannot deserialize pointers from your binary. You need to store their size information and contents in the file instead.